# select onchange updates another select with remote_function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I use Rails 3.0.3

I've 2 `<select>`, when the user choose an option in the first `<select>`, the second should be updated. The `onchange` event on the first select fire an ajax request to get the list(JSON format), the `success` event call a function that transform the JSON to a list of `<option>` to be inserted in the second `<select>`.

Here the first `<select>`

```
<%= collection_select :brand, :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, {}, {:onchange => "#{remote_function :url => brands_by_category_path(:category_id => ???), :success => "buildOptions(request, 'contract_brand_id')"}"} %>
```

the parameter of `brands_by_category_path` (???) should be egal to the selected option of this `<select>`

I really don't know how to achieve that?!!

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont use this ugly inline stuff, with rails 3 (its supports 100% unobstructive javascript).

add a javascript tag after this and do this:

1. get this select element by id
2. set up an event listener for the change event
3. add a call back to this event
4. make sure the call does this: `brands_by_category_path(this.selected)`